# DataAnnotation for Date

Tags: regex, data-annotations

I got a problem using DataAnnotations, here is my code:

```
[Display(Name = "Admission date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
[Date(ErrorMessage = "Date for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")]
public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
```

It works perfectly (IF I COMENT this below code):

```
[Display(Name = "Leadership date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format")]
[Date(ErrorMessage = "Date for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must be a date.")]
public Nullable<DateTime> HeadShipDate { get; set; }
```

I don't know why, but it really happens, I commented the Regex validation for HeadShipDate, and AdmissionDate validation works, if I uncomment the that validation for HeadShipDate, it seems confused and match any date.

Btw, is the same Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for HeadShipDate needs to be within a string and begin with the @ sign, like the first one.  What you posted won't compile.

Comment: I just forget the @, BUT, it's not the problem, I test with the @, and nothing, maybe it's a DataAnnotation bug, 1 validation is manipulating the other.